# Flutter onPressed() vs onTap()

Tags: flutter

I've been using Flutter for about 8 weeks.
It's awesome, no question.

However, there has been something bugging me since I've started, and that is, why do some widgets have an `onTap` method whilst others have `onPressed`? Google has not been able to give me any answers.

*If this is not relevant or on-topic enough for Stack Overflow, sorry about that, please point me to the right community to ask.*

Comment: onPressed is usually on buttons while onTap is For any other widget you add behavior to with smtin lyk InkWell or GestureDetector. My observation though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In my experience, `onTap()` is used for any gesture capture and `onPressed()` especially for buttons.
Just like in real life, when you have to use a button, you'll press it.

Hope this will solve your troubles even though I'm not totally sure about that.

Answer (score 16):

Currently they both are same. Just use **onPressed with Buttons** and **onTap with other widgets**.

Flutter is still new so there are lots of overlaps. May be in future updates they will make it more streamline . Like they will merge many widgets which are almost same.

Answer (score 3):

The Source of differents between `onTap` and `onPressed` is **GestureDetector** used in buttons.
**onTap** should give you response in the first moment touching the screen.
**onPressed** should be equvalent to .onTapDown property - the last moment touching the screen.