# Flutter onTap() and onPressed()

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter but I also have a question as regarding the Flutter onTap() and onPressed(). If the onTap() is for widgets and the onPressed() is for button, why does Navigation (Navigator.push and Navigator.pop) just allow for onPressed().

It has been quite disturbing to me.

Comment: It is allowed for both of them. Let me know about your issue/error.

Comment: There are the same, with different names.

Answer (score 1):

```
onTap ()=> Navigator.of(context).push(..)
onPressed()=> Navigator.of(context).push(..)
```

Both will Work

Answer (score 0):

Let's think this way, `onPressed` used for button and `onTap` for any gesture. And there is nothing wrong with routing.

Most buttons use `onPressed`. If you look at `InkWell` it uses `onTap`.

Let's talk about `GestureDetector`. It provides many options like

```
    this.onTapDown,
    this.onTapUp,
    this.onTap,
    this.onTapCancel,
    this.onSecondaryTap,
    this.onSecondaryTapDown,
    this.onSecondaryTapUp,
    this.onSecondaryTapCancel,
    this.onTertiaryTapDown,
    this.onTertiaryTapUp,
    this.onTertiaryTapCancel,
    this.onDoubleTapDown,
    this.onDoubleTap,
    this.onDoubleTapCancel,
    this.onLongPress,
    this.onLongPressStart,
    this.onLongPressMoveUpdate,
    this.onLongPressUp,
    this.onLongPressEnd,
    .................
```

I think you will never find a widget that contains both `onTap` and  `onPressed.

For more, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57526650/10157127) .